# Rating mechanism for a product in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, ios4

I am implementing a project in which I am getting the product list from a json array using sbjson framework. I want to know that how can I implement a rating mechanism for each product.e.g. if I select product 2 and want to rate it from 1-5 and save it on the server.

Next time when I again click on that product it will show the average of all times when a user has rated it and also allow user to rate it when any product is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the rating UI controls available, such as: https://github.com/dlinsin/DLStarRating

Then, of course, you need to implement the server side code to handle new rating submissions and all times average rating calculations for a product etc.